# Adding Models to A Backbone Paginator Collection

Tags: backbone.js, socket.io

I have a View displaying a Collection built using [Backbone Paginator's](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator) clientPager. Everything works very well on page load.

I also have the client-side code hooked up to Socket.IO which fires model add events every once in a while. I add the model to the Backbone Paginator collection, which then fires the 'add' event in the view:

```
add: function(call){
      var collection = this.collection;

      var $div = this.$(this.div);
        var call_view = CallsView.generateView(call, collection, this.type);
        var html = call_view.render().el;
        $(html).hide().prependTo(this.div).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

This code also works well. However, it doesn't update the pagination. Is there a standard way to do this with Backbone Paginator? I'm a bit lost at this point. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a way to update the paginator?